# <c:out/> unknown tag

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tags, jstl

Why I get error tip message in eclipse on left when I include the following line.

```
<c:out value=${variable}/>
```

I get the error "Unknown tag(c:out)"

I also included on top

```
<%@ page isELIgnored ="false" %>
```

Is there a jstl I need to include?

Comment: Please see my answer to this eclipse warnings at: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22708241/unknown-tag-cforeach-in-eclipse][1]

Comment: Please see my answer to these eclipse warnings at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22708241/unknown-tag-cforeach-in-eclipse

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You're apparently developing with a servlet container which does not support JSTL out the box, such as Tomcat. In that case, you need to download [jstl-1.2.jar](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar) and drop in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of your webapp. **No** other changes are necessary, also not extracting the JAR file and/or littering the `/WEB-INF` folder with loose TLD files as some poor online tutorials suggest.

After having dropped the JAR file in the classpath (the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder is part of the webapp's runtime classpath), you should be able to reference the JSTL core taglib by putting the following line in top of your JSP as per [its documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html):

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

JSTL 1.2 requires a minimum of Servlet 2.4 declaration in `web.xml`. So make sure that your `web.xml` has the proper root declaration, preferably the highest supported version as supported by your servlet container (Tomcat 7 is Servlet 3.0, Tomcat 6 is Servlet 2.5 and Tomcat 5.5 is Servlet 2.4).

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) (you can get to this page by putting your mouse above the `[jstl]` tag which you put on the question yourself and clicking the *info* link on the popbox)

Comment: Finally a nice complete answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a link for the JSTL Library on that page. [This](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-jstl-on-my-jsps.html) tutorial should provide you with the necessary information.

Comment: I included the JSTL `http://java.sun.com/jstl/core` and even tried `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core`.
The error displayed is `Can not find the tag library descriptor for http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core`

Comment: Please make a sample page with some sample code and paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

I am studying Spring Framework Security tutorial.
I imported a maven tutorial project, compiled and saw the warning "<c:out> unknown tag".
The jstl-1.2.jar was already on the project class path. The problem was that the project came with 1.6
run time library, and I have only 1.7 installed on my machine. I replaced the libraries and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add the given line on top of the JSP file:

> `<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>`

And, one more thing you need to do is,
Copy the dependency from this [maven repo link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/jstl-api/1.2) & paste it on **`pom.xml`** of the project.

Answer (score 0):

If ur using maven dependency see wether the jstl 1.2 dependency is added properly then.
`<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`   use this tag in ur jsp page.
And also if its geving url error then just rewrite the url and save it.
And also change the version of java to 8 and change the spring boot version to 2.7.17

Answer (score -1):

I faced same issue during practice coding with jsp. Following worked for me - (In short)

Use `jstl 1.2.jar` in place of `jstl.jar`
with:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```