# Unknown tag (c:foreach). in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jstl

I have jstl code  and it builds by maven well... But Eclipse had compilation error "Unknown tag (c:foreach)."

code are here:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <c:forEach items="${listOfMyFriends}" var="friend">
        <c:out value="${friend}"></c:out>
        </c:forEach>

    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

could someone help me to avoid this promlem?

There are full pom: `
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.godzevych</groupId>
<artifactId>springInActionMVCTemplate</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>springInActionMVCTemplate</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.6</java.version>
    <spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring core & mvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- CGLib for @Configuration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>${cglib.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Servlet Spec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSR 330 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>springsource-milestones</id>
        <name>SpringSource Milestones Proxy</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/springsource-milestones</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <finalName>springInActionMVCTemplate</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`

Comment: did you add this dependency?
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: yes but without scope... now add but no changes...

Comment: JSTL 1.2 requires a minimum of Servlet 2.4 declaration in web.xml. So make sure that your web.xml has the proper root declaration, preferably the highest supported version as supported by your servlet container (Tomcat 7 is Servlet 3.0, Tomcat 6 is Servlet 2.5 and Tomcat 5.5 is Servlet 2.4).

Comment: see additions I run on tomcat 6 and Servlet 2.5... Could it be a only eclipse problem? because application compile and runs well, but eclipse show compilation warning...

Comment: @BalusC why this is duplicated? @Capril has mentioned in question, `jstl` library has been added but warning still there. I see @Osmar answer, it solved my same problem because the stupid space.

Comment: I agree, I don't see this as a duplicate. The question referred to as a duplicate is about the general task of installing, and this is about what turned out to be a particular error in the declaration. It would be very hard for a user to identify and isolate the info that would solve this question in referenced question.

Answer (score 25):

Same thing was happening to me in Eclipse. It disappeared after I deleted the white space between `<%@` and `taglib` that appears in your code.

So now it appears like this and the warning is gone:

```
<%@taglib  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Answer (score 17):

What you actually need is to add the following line on top of your JSP files:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Also, you need to download the JSTL jar files from [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-taglibs.cgi) and add them to `WEB_INF/lib` folder.

Found my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8400733/3758439

Answer (score 5):

I was also getting this warning in eclipse. I was also getting other warnings such as:

> Unknown tag `(c:if)` or Unknown tag `(c:set)` etc.

To fix these warning in eclipse, all i did was to include the following dependency in my pom file. Please note that I am using the servlet 2.5 api.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

You seem to be using `<provided>` for this dependency in your pom file. Maybe that's causing your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

the correct tag is case sensitive. (c:forEach)

Comment: The original post already has the correct formatting.