# Button click doesn't result in any action in jsp file

Tags: jsp

I have this simple code from a book that I'm working through, which displays a simple form with an Add button, but nothing happens when I click the button. This is the jsp:

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!--  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22708241/unknown-tag-cforeach-in-eclipse -->    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Add Course</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:set var="errMsg" value="${null}"/>
    <c:set var="displayForm" value="${true}"/>

    <c:if test="${\"POST\".equalsIgnoreCase(pageContext.request.method) 
                && pageContext.request.getParameter(\"submit\") != null}">
        <jsp:useBean id="courseBean" class="packt.book.jee.eclipse.ch4.bean.Course">
            <c:catch var="beanStorageException">
                <jsp:setProperty name="courseBean" property="*" />
            </c:catch>
        </jsp:useBean>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${!courseBean.isValidCourse() || beanStorageException != null}">
                <c:set var="errMsg" value="Invalid course details. Please try again"/>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <c:catch var="addCourseException">
                    ${courseBean.addCourse()}
                </c:catch>
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${addCourseException != null}">
                        <c:set var="errMsg" value="${addCourseException.message}"/>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <c:redirect url="listCourse.jsp"/>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:if>

    <jsp:useBean id="teacherBean" class="packt.book.jee.eclipse.ch4.bean.Teacher"/>
    <c:catch var="teacherBeanErr">
        <c:set var="teachers" value="${teacherBean.getTeachers()}"/>
    </c:catch>
    <c:if test="${teacherBeanErr != null}">
        <c:set var="errMsg" value="${err.message}"/>
    </c:if>

    <h2>Add Course:</h2>
    <c:if test="${errMsg != null}">
        <span style="color: red;">
            <c:out value="${errMsg}"></c:out>
        </span>
    </c:if>
    <form method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
        Credits : <input type="text" name="credits"> <br>
        Teacher : <select name="teacherId">
            <c:forEach items="${teachers}" var="teacher">
                <option value="${teacher.id}">${teacher.firstName}</option>
            </c:forEach>        
        </select>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Add</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

The trouble is, when I click on the Add button, nothing happens. Is there a problem in the book's code? Books are notoriously bad in this area. It seems there are many ways to submit form data; here a button is being used but there is no "action" attribute; so is the page being submitted to itself? If so, why isn't it working?

```
<form method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
    Credits : <input type="text" name="credits"> <br>
    Teacher : <select name="teacherId">
        <c:forEach items="${teachers}" var="teacher">
            <option value="${teacher.id}">${teacher.firstName}</option>
        </c:forEach>        
    </select>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

This is what the form looks like:

[image: The form]

Thanks very much in advance.

EDIT: I have since found that you need to explicitly disable JSTL EL being ignored with

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

I am still having problems however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was that EL was disabled; I enabled it with this

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to provide form action =yourmethod, which on submit should do your logic.

Comment: Thanks; it was something else.