# Spring controller doesn't show data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

With this controller

```
package com.companyname.springapp.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
@Controller
public class HelloController {

     protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

        @RequestMapping(value="/hello.htm")
        public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

            String now = (new Date()).toString();
            logger.info("Returning hello view with " + now);

            return new ModelAndView("WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp", "now", now);
        }

}
```

Shows the view

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/include.jsp" %>

<html>
  <head><title>Hello :: Spring Application</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello - Spring Application</h1>
    <p>Greetings, it is now <c:out value="${now}"/></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

include.jsp

```
<%@ page session="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

When is executed the view shows ´it is now now´ ,doesn't shows the date value,I  have a warning ´Unknown tag (c:out)´ I have the same warning on the redirect tag but it works.

jstl jar its on maven dependencies list

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>taglibs-standard-spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: please verify if you have jstl jar in classpath.. also check if this is helpful, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400301/cout-unknown-tag

Comment: jstl jar is on maven dependencies list